# 2 similar recursive IEnumerators behave weird

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a recursive `IEnumerator` which looks like this :

```
IEnumerator Spawn()
{
    if(canSpawn)
    {               
        Vector3 offset = new Vector3(example.transform.position.x + offsetVar, example.transform.position.y, example.transform.position.z);
        Instantiate(someObject, offset,Quaternion.identity);
        canSpawn = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(cooldown);
        canSpawn = true;
        StartCoroutine(Spawn());
    }        
}
```

And I use `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(string s)` in `Start()` method to locate the `example` game object. I call this  `IEnumerator` once with  a copy of this `IEnumerator` which just has different variables. It works as expected but the distance between the object this `IEnumerator` instantiates and the another one keeps getting smaller and smaller until they both get instantiated at the same position. What could be the problem here ?

Comment: Just possible: when you instantiate an object with the same tag and move it on X axis for a specific offset, and then look up this object, it takes a new one that is closer, and then instantiates new block with new offset. This means you just recursively spawn objects on a line right?

Answer (score 1):

It was because that I started both of the coroutines in a method and I was calling that method in `Update()` method. Now I call them only once and this problem does not occur.